# How to remove unwanted rows and create new column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables.

My first table is called as WORLD and this table have a column named PEOPLE. In PEOPLE table I have both women's and men's names.

My second table is called as MEN and this table has a column named NAMES. It consists of men's names.

What I want to do is by comparing those two tables finding women's names and adding them to a column named "WOMEN" in the WORLD table.

**WORLD.PEOPLE**                          **MEN.NAMES**

```
John                John
Joe                 Alan
Jessica             Michael
Martin              Martin
Alan                Adam
Eva                 Joe
Mary
```

What I want to have is:

**WORLD.PEOPLE**                   **WORLD.WOMEN**

```
John                Jessica
Joe                 Eva
Jessica             Mary
Martin              
Alan                
Eva                 
Mary
```

I tried using this statement:

> SELECT People FROM WORLD WHERE  (People NOT IN(SELECT Names FROM MEN)))

However this only gives result, it doesn't update the WORLD table.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to Create a new table and add the values there and then drop the WORLD table.
 I guess you just want to work on one single database, but i can't think any other easier way. With insert you will get null values so it won't be practical. You can try what i said.

Answer (score 1):

You must have some key field in table WORLD for identification records.
Or use another table for store women names.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO world(women) SELECT People FROM WORLD WHERE (People NOT IN(SELECT Names FROM MEN)))
```

or something like that?
Also, see [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).
I'm not sure if the above syntax is correct, because you're inserting data to a table by selecting data from the same table. Maybe you need to use "AS".

Comment: If you see the documentation i'm linking, the SET is not a part of the INSERT...SELECT syntax. Did you try the code?